# Spring security don't asks for login and password

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to learn [this](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.23.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/index.html#_business_application_with_dynamic_assets) JBPM example, but code not compiles after cloning from git. I change dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-server-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Application:

```
package com.company.service;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Config:

```
package com.company.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;


@Configuration("kieServerSecurity")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DefaultWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/rest/*").authenticated()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password(encoder.encode("user")).roles("kie-server");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("wbadmin").password(encoder.encode("wbadmin")).roles("admin");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("kieserver").password(encoder.encode("kieserver")).roles("kie-server");
}
}
```

Now application compiles, then start `launch.bat clean install`.

Next, I'm trying to check URL http://localhost:8090/rest/server/containers in FF, and application does not asking for login-password, and shows XML response. If I connect to this URL from another computer, results are same - not asking password and shows XML.

Where is my error? Why spring not asks password and how to fix this?

Comment: Change `.antMatchers("/rest/*")` to `.antMatchers("/rest/**")`.

Comment: Yes, changing to `.antMatchers("/rest/**")` did the trick.